# Magento Notification Emails

Tags: php, email, magento

I have recently been given the task of fixing a bug on a Magento store online and im having trouble finding the solution.

When a new order is made, the administrator receives an email (which is fine) however the FROM: part of the notification email contains the customers name and the shared servers hostname.. EG:

```
[customername]@[serverhostname.com]
```

It's not a massive issue but it is annoying.. After looking all over in the Admin area, I am unable to find the config setting which gives this weird email address..

Upon looking in the `System > Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses`, and looking in `System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails` the email address is not found in any of the fields nor are any settings set for sending notifications emails to the administrator. **WEIRD!**

The only thing I can think is that this may have been hardcoded within the Magento install..

Is anyone able to point me in the right place where I might be able to find this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest installing SMTP-Pro so that the email can be sent via the SMTP server in the same way an email client such as outlook would.

The extension also has some great debugging and other features

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html